# Como realizar consulta a horas en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una base de datos mas o menos asi

```
---------------------------------
| inicio   | fin     |    dato  |
---------------------------------
|   14:00  |  18:30  |    A     |
---------------------------------
|   19:00  |  23:30  |    B     |
---------------------------------
|   07:15  |  12:00  |    C     |
---------------------------------
```

Posterior tengo la hora actual por ejemplo `15:23`, dicha hora esta en el rango de `14:00 - 18:30 - A` que es el dato que sedeo obtener.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Dato::where("inicio",">=",Carbon::now()->toTimeString())->where("fin","<=",Carbon::now()->toTimeString())->get();
```

Pero No me funciona.

Comment: para trabajar con horas en laravel tienes `wheretime` aqui un ejemplo `$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereTime('created_at', '=', '11:20:45')
                ->get();`

Comment: Si `inicio >= hora actual` y `fin <= hora actual` nunca vas a estar dentro del rango, sería al contrario